# Static IP configuration with ip command in Linux gives Destination Host Unreachable

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv4, static-ip

I am a total newbie when it comes to network configuration. I would like to configure my Ubuntu 18.04 PC so that it connects to a device.

I use USB to Ethernet converter and connect the ethernet jack to the device and USB connector to my PC. Regarding the device, the only information I got is device is accessible via 172.16.250.248 IP address. For that, I think I need to configure the particular network interface I use to connect to that device as static IP.

For this I execute following commands;

```
HOST_USB_IP=172.16.250.248
TARGET_USB_IP=172.16.250.201
INTERFACE_NAME=enxd03745fbecb2
sudo ip route del default via $HOST_USB_IP
sudo ifconfig $INTERFACE_NAME $TARGET_USB_IP netmask 255.255.0.0
sudo route add default gw $HOST_USB_IP
```

However, I get the following when I try to ping the device:

```
PING 172.16.248.248 (172.16.250.248) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 172.16.248.201 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.248.201 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 172.16.248.201 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

What am I missing here? What else can I try? Any guidance is much appreciated.

**EDIT: ifconfig**

```
enxd03745fbecb2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.16.250.201  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.16.255.255
        inet6 fe80::d237:45ff:fefb:ecb2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d0:37:45:fb:ec:b2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 91  bytes 12018 (12.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1078  bytes 85079 (85.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1078  bytes 85079 (85.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

**EDIT: tcpdump**

```
sudo tcpdump -v
tcpdump: listening on enxd03745fbecb2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
08:18:17.290897 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:18.314986 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:19.338822 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:19.959793 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 255, id 22638, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 203)
    mozcelikors-monster.mdns > 224.0.0.251.mdns: 0 [1a] [9q] PTR (QM)? _nfs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ftp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdav._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdavs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _sftp-ssh._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _smb._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _afpovertcp._tcp.local. (175)
08:18:20.362865 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:20.938829 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) mozcelikors-monster > ip6-allrouters: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router solicitation, length 16
      source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): d0:37:45:fb:ec:b2
08:18:21.036788 IP6 (flowlabel 0x2e07e, hlim 255, next-header UDP (17) payload length: 183) mozcelikors-monster.mdns > ff02::fb.mdns: [bad udp cksum 0x032d -> 0x63ac!] 0 [1a] [9q] PTR (QM)? _nfs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ftp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdav._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdavs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _sftp-ssh._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _smb._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _afpovertcp._tcp.local. (175)
08:18:37.770915 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:38.794818 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:39.819006 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:48.014902 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:49.034975 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:18:58.250915 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:07.467009 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:08.490891 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:09.514859 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:10.538961 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:11.562886 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:12.587390 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:13.611026 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:14.635375 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:15.659392 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:16.683480 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:17.706796 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:18.731178 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
08:19:19.754945 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has _gateway tell mozcelikors-monster, length 28
^C
26 packets captured
66 packets received by filter
40 packets dropped by kernel
```

**EDIT: tcpdump -vni enxd03745fbecb2**

```
tcpdump: listening on enxd03745fbecb2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:01:53.745827 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:01:54.777111 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:01:55.801017 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:01:56.825115 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:01:57.849117 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:01:58.873092 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:01:59.901121 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:02:00.921096 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
09:02:01.945080 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.16.250.248 tell 172.16.250.201, length 28
```

Comment: Does this PC have any other active network interfaces while you try this testing?  Then try disconnecting them while performing your test.

Comment: As ever, run `tcpdump` and see what is on the wire. Also edit the post with the output of plain `ifconfig $INTERFACE_NAME`. It's possible that the subnet on the gw is too small and the IP address of the host is outwith it.

Comment: @Bib the question has been updated with the tcpdump and ifconfig. Please take a look. Also note I changed some IP addresses but it does not change the status. With 248.x IP address I get the same result.

Comment: Can you clarify whether your device is .248.248 or .248.201? Your post says the device is "accessible via 172.16.248.248" but your config shows the opposite.

Comment: (Also, generally, tcpdump should be used with the `-n` option to show the raw IP addresses and avoid the possibly misleading reverse name lookups, i.e. `tcpdump -vn` or `tcpdump -vni eth0`.)

Comment: The device (host) is 172.16.250.248, PC (target) is 172.16.250.201. Netmask is 255.255.0.0.
I updated the question with the command you suggested. I also updated question to avoid confusion.

Comment: It still sounds to me like you have "host" and "target" swapped – if you're configuring this within the PC, then the PC would be the host, not the target.

Comment: The connection host is the device, that was my thinking, anyhow do you suggest anything here?

Answer (score 0):

The commands you've run have effectively configured the USB dongle to use 172.16.250.201/16.

Unless there's *another* device in your network using 172.16.250.248, there's nothing you can ping. Another device is unlikely since you seem to have gotten that address via DHCP which ensures there's no address collision. Also, you've set that supposedly non-existent address as default gateway.

Static IP configuration may be cumbersome. You might want to look for configuring a *reserved address* for that device on your DHCP server if you don't want its address to change. That way, default gateway and DNS assignment still come via DHCP and require no manual fiddling.